'_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
i am getting this error Map<String, dynamic> is not a subtype of type String while trying to use provider and i confused where the error is.
have a look at my model
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
import 'dart:convert';

class User {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final int phone;
  final String? image;
  final String location;
  final String sex;
  final String password;
  final String? age;
  final String? preferredLocation;
  final List<dynamic>? education;
  final List<dynamic>? workExperience;
  final String role;
  final List<dynamic>? applications;
  final List<dynamic>? favoriteJobs;
  User({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
    required this.phone,
    this.image,
    required this.location,
    required this.sex,
    required this.password,
    this.age,
    this.preferredLocation,
    this.education,
    this.workExperience,
    required this.role,
    this.applications,
    this.favoriteJobs,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'phone': phone,
      'image': image,
      'location': location,
      'sex': sex,
      'password': password,
      'age': age,
      'preferredLocation': preferredLocation,
      'education': education,
      'workExperience': workExperience,
      'role': role,
      'applications': applications,
      'favoriteJobs': favoriteJobs,
    };
  }

  factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return User(
      id: map['_id'] ?? "",
      name: map['name'] ?? "",
      email: map['email'] ?? "",
      phone: map['phone'] ?? 0,
      image: map['image'] ?? "",
      location: map['location'] ?? "",
      sex: map['sex'] ?? "",
      password: map['password'] ?? "",
      age: map['age'] ?? "",
      preferredLocation: map['preferredLocation'] ?? "",
      education: map['education'] != null
          ? List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
              (map['education']?.map((x) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(x))))
          : [],
      workExperience: map['workExperience'] != null
          ? List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
              (map['workExperience']?.map((x) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(x))))
          : [],
      role: map['role'] ?? "job_seeker",
      applications: map['applications'] != null
          ? List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
              (map['applications']?.map((x) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(x))))
          : [],
      favoriteJobs: map['favoriteJobs'] != null
          ? List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
              (map['favoriteJobs']?.map((x) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(x))))
          : [],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory User.fromJson(String source) =>
      User.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);
}


and my provider is looking like this
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:job_finder_app/models/usermodel.dart';

class AllusersProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<User> _users = [];

  List<User> get users => _users;


`  void setUsers(List<User> users) {
`    _users = users;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addUser(User user) {
    _users.add(user);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeUser(User user) {
    _users.remove(user);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}

i printed the response and i am getting my responses as json and it looks the data but i can't use it in Ui because I am getting Map<String, dynamic> is not a subtype of type String

recheck your response's data fields (image, location...etc), because you are treating a field as a String while it's a Map

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

The error 'FirstType' is not a subtype of type 'SecondType' means that dart tried to cast/convert FirstType into SecondType. In your case _Map<String, dynamic> into String.
Note underscore "_" before "Map" in type name inside error message. _Map is one of the underlying types that json.decode uses to store parsed json objects (It could be _JsonMap or other internal (underscore-prefixed) type). Than you tried to use that _Map<String, dynamic> object as a String inside your User.fromMap method. Please check all the fields that you expect to be strings in your api response, but are object instead (I'd guess it's either "location" or "preferredLocation" fields).


i printed the response and i am getting my responses as json and it looks the data

Use api testing tool (like Postman) to fully inspect the response or print the types of each value inside your json.decode(source) object to see which ones are misaligned by:
json.decode(source).forEach((k, v) {
  print('{ key: $k, value type: ${v.runtimeType}}');
});

